MT5 python module: downloading OHLC data
I am trying to download OHLC data from MT5 using the python module.  if I use copy_rates_from_pos, all works fine.
If I use dates, the problem is the resulting data is not aligned with the times on the chart.
Background: My broker is GMT +2/+3.  It changes daylight savings based upon NYC.  So there are no timezone that fits this situation (for example, I used Athens, but daylight savings changes on a different date).
I have tried 3 things:

I just put date range with datetime objects with no timezone information.

Ex. Code: now_date = datetime.now()).

Result: It gives me candles 3 hours before the latest candle on the current chart.  For example, the latest candle on the chart is 8:03.  The latest candle in the dataframe is 5:03.  Now the candle's OHLC data in the dataframe is accurate to the OHLC 5:03 candle on the chart.

I tried changing timezone to UTC, as per suggestion on MT5 website.

Ex. Code: now_date = datetime.now(pytz.timezone("Etc/UTC")).  

Result: it gave a time of 1 hour behind the latest candle on the chart.  The OHLC data does not line up with any candles of the same minutes on the chart (meaning, I compared to latest candle, 1 hour behind that, 1 hour back, etc.).

I used UTC and NYC timezones and converted it using GMT offset of my broker.
Ex. Code:

nyc_timezone = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
utc_now = datetime.now(pytz.utc)
nyc_time = utc_now.astimezone(nyc_timezone)
if nyc_time.dst() != timedelta(0):
    broker_offset = 3 - (-4)  # +3 GMT minus -4 GMT (NYC DST offset)
else:
    broker_offset = 2 - (-5)  # +2 GMT minus -5 GMT (NYC standard offset)
broker_time = nyc_time + timedelta(hours=broker_offset)
broker_time = broker_time.replace(second=0, microsecond=0)

Result: it gave a time of 1 hour behind the latest candle on the chart.  The OHLC data does not line up with any candles of the same minutes on the chart (meaning, I compared to latest candle, 1 hour behind that, 1 hour back, etc.).
So, can someone guide me on how to download data using MT5 module using dates?  I cannot figure this out.  Thanks in advance.

This is what I found worked for me:
# Download the current time in GMT
now_date = datetime.now(pytz.timezone("Etc/UTC"))
# Removed the seconds, because I want latest minute candle
now_date = now_date.replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
# Subtract by 1 minute, because I want the latest complete candle, not the one that is being formed
now_date = now_date - timedelta(minutes=1)
# Get the NYC timezone
nyc_timezone = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
nyc_time = datetime.now(nyc_timezone)
# Then change the GMT timezone to my current timezone, based upon if NYC is in daylight savings or not.  If it is, then nyc_time.dst() = 1 hour, which will change my now time to +3 GMT.  If not, then it is 0 and my calc is +2 GMT.
latest_candle = now_date + nyc_time.dst() + timedelta(hours=2)
# Last lesson is you put the date of the last candle to download (most recent), then it will go back in time the number of bars you are asking for.
df = cdl.download(Pairname,latest_candle,Num_candles,NumCandlesBackForHL)

